# Cannot launch a desktop file using wine

Tags: wine, .desktop

I am not entirely sure this is the right place to post but I have Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS on my computer, and I tried playing the nostalgic game "Transformers: Fall of Cybertron". I found a windows copy, and since I am a total noob in linux, I probably missing some obious answers to this. When I try in Terminal:

```
wine "/home/danielgrant/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/Activision/Transformers Fall of Cybertron/Transformers Fall of Cybertron.desktop"
```

I get the following error:

```
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

0054:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver L"\\Registry\\Machine\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\nsiproxy": c0000003
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

0024:err:process:exec_process L"Z:\\home\\danielgrant\\.local\\share\\applications\\wine\\Programs\\Activision\\Transformers Fall of Cybertron\\Transformers Fall of Cybertron.desktop" not supported on this system
```

I have no Idea where even to start, so I would appreciate every help possible.

Answer (score 0):

`Desktop` files are meant to be launched by your graphical desktop environment, you cannot launch them as applications (that's what you're doing).

You can inspect the file by running `cat "/home/danielgrant/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/Activision/Transformers Fall of Cybertron/Transformers Fall of Cybertron.desktop"` and then using the string after `Exec=` to launch it. It might also contain the `Path=` variable, so you'd better `cd "directory"` into it first.

Alternatively check this answer how to launch `*desktop` files from console: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the program by launching the desktop file using wine, you can run the program by launching wine using the desktop file.

Edit the desktop file, change the Type entry to `Application`, and change the Exec entry to `wine <path to exe file>`.

As an example, here's a working desktop file for launching a Windows exe of an old video game on my system...

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Asteroids
Comment=
Exec=wine '/home/David/C/Program Files (x86)/Atari/The 80 Classic Games/Asteroids.exe'
Icon=/home/David/System/Icons/Local Shared Icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/54DF_Menu.0.png
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
```